# Does a byte primitive become a byte in memory when indirectly inside an array?

Tags: java, memory, arrays

I have heard that a byte by itself takes up 4 bytes in memory, and a byte inside a byte array takes 1 byte, but what about a byte member variable inside an object that is within an array?

```
class SomeObject {
    byte iBite;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeObject[] objs = ...
}
```

Will each SomeObject have its `iBite` variable only be 1 byte in memory?

Comment: No, it will be 'a byte by itself' and take up 4 bytes, if for no other reason that object sizes will almost certainly be rounded up.

Comment: Objects have at least an 8 byte overhead, and are aligned on 8-byte boundaries, your object is 8+1=9 bytes (at least), so will take up 16 bytes in memory. The array is storing references to objects, which are themselves at least 4 bytes long, so `SomeObject[100]` uses 100*(16+4)=2000 bytes (at least) of memory (assuming different objects assigned to full array), while `byte[100]` uses 100 bytes of memory. Both are in addition to the 12+ bytes of overhead for the array itself.

Comment: A byte inside an object will take 1-4 bytes, depending on the phase of the moon.

Comment: @Andreas An array of 100 "objects" takes 100 times the size of a single reference (ie, pointer).  (The objects themselves of course take more, but they are allocated separately.)

Comment: @HotLicks I know. That's why I said 100 * 4 for the references, plus 100 * 16 for the objects, i.e. **100** * (16 + **4**) = 2000 bytes.

Comment: @Andreas - SomeObject[100] may not reference any objects at all.  And even if it does, they are not part of the array object.

Comment: @HotLicks Which is why I said "assuming **different** objects assigned to **full** array", i.e. references are not null and are not referencing the same objects.

Comment: @Andreas - And who did you expect to understand that?

Comment: At  Dalvik Vm all fields need 32 bit except long and double which need 64bit (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824677/is-dalvik-even-more-memory-hungry-than-hotspot-in-terms-of-object-sizes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A byte as a *local variable* is implemented as an `int`, so it takes 4 bytes.

A byte as a *field of a class* (like in your example) takes 1 byte of memory, but classes in memory are rounded up to multiples of 8 bytes on e.g. HotSpot JVMs.  That said, if you have a class with multiple `byte` fields (or `char` or `short` fields), those will make more efficient use of memory.

Arrays are similar: each `byte` will take 1 byte, but the array as a whole will be rounded up to a multiple of 8 bytes on e.g. HotSpot JVMs.

You can experiment with this by hand using http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/.  If you use it, for example, on

```
public static class A {
    boolean f;
    byte g;
    int h;
}
```

I get

```
Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Using compressed oop with 3-bit shift.
Using compressed klass with 3-bit shift.
Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

org.openjdk.jol.samples.JOLSample_01_Basic.A object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE    TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0    12         (object header)                N/A
     12     4     int A.h                            N/A
     16     1 boolean A.f                            N/A
     17     1    byte A.g                            N/A
     18     6         (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 24 bytes (estimated, the sample instance is not available)
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 6 bytes external = 6 bytes total
```

which exhibits pretty clearly that `boolean` and `byte` take one byte as object fields.

As you'd expect, `char` and `short` are 2 bytes, `int` and `float` are 4 bytes, `long` and `double` are 8 bytes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14782255/869736 explains some details on Dalvik, including that currently small fields like `byte` are in fact implemented with 4 bytes.  Remember that these details *are* going to be VM-dependent.

Comment: A byte as field of class needs 4 bytes.

Comment: @AlexWien not on normal HotSpot VMs.

Comment: Event on hotspot, where have you your information from?

Comment: @AlexWien A single field will be padded out, so while a byte field may need 4 bytes, 4 byte fields will also only need 4 bytes. :)

Comment: @AlexWien you can experiment with this by hand using http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/, which is about as authoritative as it gets, since it comes from the OpenJDK folks who actually write Java.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Even a naked `Unsafe.objectFieldOffset()` call will reveal the truth.

Comment: At dalvik used in android I think it is 4 bytes.

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding, char, short, float and double ;-)

Comment: You answer is only valid for HotSpot, Dalvik is different you should note that, not only in th e.g at HostSpot...

Comment: @AlexWien The crucial requirement for implementing packed structures like this is for the hardware to support the update of a single byte in a word, without affecting its neighbours. This is needed for the Java Memory Model guarantees of multithreaded access, and if the CPU can't do it, the VM must store bytes unpacked.

Comment: @biziclop So you mean its an caused by the ARM processors used in embedded devices, like ARM7 to 9 ? not by Dalvik itself?

Comment: Thank you for the jol tool. Never knew about it.

Comment: Even the statement about local variables is implementation dependent. While it is true that the bytecode instruction set doesn’t make a difference between `byte`, `short`, `char`, `boolean` and `int`, the implementation still is free to make a distinction when narrowing the type is possible (which can deduced from context). Similarly, the same instructions are use for dealing with arrays of type `byte` and `boolean`, but the JVM still might decide to store boolean arrays differently. Further, local variables might get mapped to CPU registers or optimized away entirely, taking no space at all.

Comment: @AlexWien I think so but I'm not that familiar with the ARM instruction set.